# compiling sse intrinsic instructions

Tags: c

I am testing pcmpistr instruction which is a strchr() equivalent in SSE but I get the error on return value, for some reason the compiler thinks that the 'int' type variable 'idx' is a vector, but it is a scalar and it should store the index of the character found in the string. What is the problem here?

```
[niko@dev1 test]$ cat pcmpistr.c
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int idx;
    char str1[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) ={'G','E','T',' ','/','i','n','d','e','x','.','h','t','m','l','\n'} ;
    char str2[1]  __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) ={'\n'};
    __m128i *a,*b;

    a=(__m128i*) str1;
    b=(__m128i*) str2;
    idx=_mm_cmpestri (a, 16, b, 1, _SIDD_UBYTE_OPS |_SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY|_SIDD_LEAST_SIGNIFICANT);

    printf("idx=%d\n",idx);
}
[niko@dev1 test]$ gcc -o pcmpstr pcmpistr.c 
pcmpistr.c: In function ‘main’:
pcmpistr.c:13:2: error: can’t convert value to a vector
  idx=_mm_cmpestri (a, 16, b, 1, _SIDD_UBYTE_OPS |_SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY|_SIDD_LEAST_SIGNIFICANT);
  ^
pcmpistr.c:13:2: error: can’t convert value to a vector
[niko@dev1 test]$
```

Comment: I think you need to dereference `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FUZxxl is right, the signature of the function is given as:

```
int _mm_cmpestri (
   __m128i a, 
   int la,
   __m128i b,
   int lb, 
   const int mode
);
```

So, you need to dereference a and b as:

```
idx=_mm_cmpestri (*a, 16, *b, 1, _SIDD_UBYTE_OPS |_SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY|_SIDD_LEAST_SIGNIFICANT);
```

Comment: Ohh, I see. compiled it but it doesn't work , it must return 15 but it returns 0 . Does it work for you?

Comment: it works, I had to swap a and b. dam it , very poor docs on sse